# Jquery animate scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var position = $window.scrollTop();

    if(position <= 2950){
        $(".lion_head").animate({right: "-100px"}, 2000);
    };
});
```

So if I scroll from `2950px` the `.lion_head` will move `-100px` from right, What I want is when I scroll down, or scroll up, or when my scroll bar is not on `2950px`, The position of my `.lion_head` moves to its original position?

thanks.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that lion-head was offset right only when scrolltop was exactly 2950px?

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: try using jQuery.ScrollTo plugin(http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: `if(position <= 2950){
    $(".lion_head").animate({right: "-100px"}, 2000);
}else{
 $(".lion_head").animate({right: "0px"}, 2000);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code inside `$(window).on('scroll', function(e){ ... });`.

In side the event function, do your animation logic.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    var position = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(position <= 2950){
       $(".lion_head").animate({right: "-100px"}, 2000);
    }
    else{
       $(".lion_head").animate({right: "0"}, 2000);
    }
});
```

See [jQuery.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use pure javascript

```
var lionHead = document.querySelector(".lion_head");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

    this.scrollY <= 2950 ? lionHead.classList.add('fixed') : lionHead.classList.remove('fixed')
}, false);
```

The Style

```
.lion_head{transition:all .3s  ease}
.fixed{right: -100px}
```

Here is the full illustration, scroll up and down to see it in action:

```js
var lionHead = document.querySelector(".lion_head");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

    this.scrollY <= 2950 ? lionHead.classList.add('fixed') : lionHead.classList.remove('fixed')
}, false);
```

```css
:root{height: 4000px}
.lion_head{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: orange;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    right: 80vw;
    transition:all .3s  ease
}
.fixed{right: -100px}
```

```html
<div class=lion_head></div>
```

Comment: I would +1 this but the OP states that on scroll positions other than 2950 it should return to its default position.  *"What I want is when I scroll down, or scroll up, or when my scroll bar is not on 2950px, The position of my .lion_head moves to its original position"*

Comment: @Moob that is correct but it doesn't make any sense since no user will ever `scroll to 2950` and stay there that is why OP is using `if(position <= 2950)`.